# Looking for a MySQL client which supports strong visual differentiation between stored connections

Tags: mysql

We're using MySQL DB and our current client is MySQL query browser.

I want some client that can be configure to show a strong visual difference between connections.

I need to easily know whether I'm working on the production environment or on the test one, so I wouldn't run hazardous queries on the production environment by mistake.

The kind of strong visual indication I'm looking for is the ability to configure the background color of the query terminal but any other sufficient idea will be very appreciated.

The operating systems we use are windows and OS X but the client doesn't have to support both.

Thanks,
Yoav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (you can try free express edition). It is a multifunctional GUI tool for working with MySQL.

All you can do is bound to a definite connection that is always displayed. For example, when working with SQL documents, the current connection is displayed in the combobox where connection can be chosen.